# How to get Property Value from MemberExpression without .Compile()?

Tags: c#, expression-trees

I'm having issues trying to get the value of an object out of the Expression Tree without using .Compile()

The object is quite simple.

```
var userModel = new UserModel { Email = "John@Doe.com"};
```

The method giving me issues looks like this.

```
private void VisitMemberAccess(MemberExpression expression, MemberExpression left)
{
    var key = left != null ? left.Member.Name : expression.Member.Name;
    if (expression.Expression.NodeType.ToString() == "Parameter")
    {
        // add the string key
        _strings.Add(string.Format("[{0}]", key));
    }
    else
    {
        // add the string parameter
        _strings.Add(string.Format("@{0}", key));

        // Potential NullReferenceException
        var val = (expression.Member as FieldInfo).GetValue((expression.Expression as ConstantExpression).Value);

        // add parameter value
        Parameters.Add("@" + key, val);
    }
}
```

The tests I'm running are quite simple

```
[Test]  // PASS
public void ShouldVisitExpressionByGuidObject ()
{
    // Setup
    var id = new Guid( "CCAF57D9-88A4-4DCD-87C7-DB875E0D4E66" );
    const string expectedString = "[Id] = @Id";
    var expectedParameters = new Dictionary<string, object> { { "@Id", id } };

    // Execute
    var actualExpression = TestExpression<UserModel>( u => u.Id == id );
    var actualParameters = actualExpression.Parameters;
    var actualString = actualExpression.WhereExpression;

    // Test
    Assert.AreEqual( expectedString, actualString );
    CollectionAssert.AreEquivalent( expectedParameters, actualParameters );
}
```

```
[Test]  // FAIL [System.NullReferenceException : Object reference not set to an instance of an object.]
public void ShouldVisitExpressionByStringObject ()
{
    // Setup
    var expectedUser = new UserModel {Email = "john@doe.com"};

    const string expectedString = "[Email] = @Email";
    var expectedParameters = new Dictionary<string, object> { { "@Email", expectedUser.Email } };

    // Execute
    var actualExpression = TestExpression<UserModel>( u => u.Email == expectedUser.Email );
    var actualParameters = actualExpression.Parameters;
    var actualString = actualExpression.WhereExpression;

    // Assert
    Assert.AreEqual( expectedString, actualString );
    CollectionAssert.AreEquivalent( expectedParameters, actualParameters );
}
```

---

I should note that changing

```
var val = (expression.Member as FieldInfo).GetValue((expression.Expression as ConstantExpression).Value);
```

to

```
var val = Expression.Lambda( expression ).Compile().DynamicInvoke().ToString();
```

will allow the test to pass, however this code needs to run on iOS, and therefore can't use `.Compile()`

Comment: Is `UserModel.Email` really a field? Or is it a property?

Comment: If it's a property then `expression` is PropertyExpression -> FieldExpression -> ConstantExpression when the code assumes just FieldExpression -> ConstantExpression -- hence the problem.

Comment: Ah, this makes sense... lemme see what I come up with.

Comment: thanks @svick, you're right. It's tripping up on the Field when it's actually a Property.

Comment: @Jon that was an adventure in patience in order to get the value out of a Property. It's not nearly as intuitive as a Field.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

***TLDR;***
Reflection is ok to use as long as you're not using `Emit` or `Compile`. In the question, the value is being extracted for `FieldInfo`, but it is not being extracted for `PropertyInfo`. Make sure you can get BOTH.

```
if ((expression.Member as PropertyInfo) != null)
{
    // get the value from the PROPERTY

}
else if ((expression.Member as FieldInfo) != null)
{
    // get the value from the FIELD
}
else
{
    throw new InvalidMemberException();
}
```

---

***Long-winded version***

So the comments pointed me in the right direction. I struggled slightly with getting the PropertyInfo, but in the end, here's what I came up with.

```
private void VisitMemberAccess(MemberExpression expression, MemberExpression left)
{
    // To preserve Case between key/value pairs, we always want to use the LEFT side of the expression.
    // therefore, if left is null, then expression is actually left. 
    // Doing this ensures that our `key` matches between parameter names and database fields
    var key = left != null ? left.Member.Name : expression.Member.Name;

    // If the NodeType is a `Parameter`, we want to add the key as a DB Field name to our string collection
    // Otherwise, we want to add the key as a DB Parameter to our string collection
    if (expression.Expression.NodeType.ToString() == "Parameter")
    {
        _strings.Add(string.Format("[{0}]", key));
    }
    else
    {
        _strings.Add(string.Format("@{0}", key));

        // If the key is being added as a DB Parameter, then we have to also add the Parameter key/value pair to the collection
        // Because we're working off of Model Objects that should only contain Properties or Fields,
        // there should only be two options. PropertyInfo or FieldInfo... let's extract the VALUE accordingly
        var value = new object();
        if ((expression.Member as PropertyInfo) != null)
        {
            var exp = (MemberExpression) expression.Expression;
            var constant = (ConstantExpression) exp.Expression;
            var fieldInfoValue = ((FieldInfo) exp.Member).GetValue(constant.Value);
            value = ((PropertyInfo) expression.Member).GetValue(fieldInfoValue, null);

        }
        else if ((expression.Member as FieldInfo) != null)
        {
            var fieldInfo = expression.Member as FieldInfo;
            var constantExpression = expression.Expression as ConstantExpression;
            if (fieldInfo != null & constantExpression != null)
            {
                value = fieldInfo.GetValue(constantExpression.Value);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            throw new InvalidMemberException();
        }

        // Add the Parameter Key/Value pair.
        Parameters.Add("@" + key, value);
    }
}
```

Essentially, if the `Member.NodeType` is a `Parameter`, then I'm going to use it as a SQL Field. `[FieldName]`

Otherwise, I'm using it as a SQL Parameter `@FieldName` ... backwards I know.

If the `Member.NodeType` is NOT a Parameter, then I check to see if it's either a Model `Field`or a Model `Property`. From there, I get the appropriate value, and add the Key/Value pair to a Dictionary to be used as SQL Parameters.

The end result is that I build a string that looks something like

```sql
SELECT * FROM TableName WHERE
[FieldName] = @FieldName
```

Then the parameters are passed

```
var parameters = new Dictionary<string, object> Parameters;
parameters.Add("@FieldName", "The value of the field");
```

Comment: That's brilliant