# How to get the caller instance from an UnaryExpression?

Tags: c#, expression

I want to have a method to create a wrapper for an `Action<sender,args>`  so when I want to call this action through this wrapper I can check to see if the caller is null or not.

Here's how I'm creating the wrapper :

```
public void Subscribe<TEventArgs>(Expression<Func<Action<object,TEventArgs>> expression)
{
    wrapper=new EventHandlerWrapper{Expression=expression};
    Subscribe<TEventArgs>(wrapper.GetHandler());
}
```

Thus I can call this method like this:

```
    var handler=new MyHandler();
    Subscribe(()=>handler.EventHandler);
```

Then I want to be able to get the caller instance (handler in the above code) using the expression

The expression that I'm passing is an `UnaryExpresison`.I could find a lot of solutions that show how we can get the caller from a `MemberExpression` but here I couldn't grab any `MemberExpression`.I have a `UnaryExpression` that its `Operand` is a `MethodCallExpression` which in return its `Object` is a `ConstantExpression` and I'm stuck here.
How can I get the caller instance?

**Update:**

BTW, `EventHandler` is not an Action itself it's a method like this :

```
public class MyHandler
{
    public void EventHandler(object sender,EventArgs e)
    {
              .....
    }
}
```

Here's the signature of `Wrapper.GetHandler()` :

```
 public Action<object, TArgs> GetHandleAction()
        {
            return (sender, args) =>
            {
                if (Handler != null)
                {
                    HandlerExpression.Compile()();
                }
            };
        }
```

`Handler` is the caller instance that I'd like to populate it using the given expression.

**To Make My Question Clear** : I would like to get the caller instance from an `Expression<Func<Action<object,object>>`.

Comment: For the full picture we miss both GetHandler() and Subscribe definitions in this line: "Subscribe<TEventArgs>(wrapper.GetHandler());

Comment: @qbik I will add them to my question

Comment: It would be very helpful if you put actual, compilable code in the question. As it is, there are so many issues with the code that it's unclear what you're even trying to do. E.g. `Subscribe` appears to be infinitely recursive, unless there's another overload you haven't given, and is `wrapper` a field or did you forget to put `var` infront of it. Also, where you've given the signature of `Wrapper.GetHandler()`, the method is in fact called `GetHandleAction()`. Please review your question, and ensure that the code included actually compiles and is as close to what you're using as possible.

Comment: @Iridium I edited my question and asked it in one simple sentence.

Answer (score 1):

You can get it like this:

```
var member = (((expression.Body as UnaryExpression).Operand as MethodCallExpression).Arguments[1] as MemberExpression);
var constant = (member.Expression as ConstantExpression);
var f = member.Member;

if ((f is FieldInfo))
{
     // here is your caller instance, do your checks.
     var callerInstance = ((FieldInfo)f).GetValue(constant.Value);
}
```

(based on: [How to get Property Value from MemberExpression without .Compile()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19718560/how-to-get-property-value-from-memberexpression-without-compile))

Answer (score 1):

In this very specific example you gave, you can extract `handler` from the expression using:

```
private static void Subscribe<TEventArgs>(Expression<Func<Action<object, TEventArgs>>> expression)
{
    var accessor = ((MethodCallExpression)((UnaryExpression)expression.Body).Operand).Arguments[1];
    var handlerFunc = Expression.Lambda<Func<object>>(accessor).Compile();
    var handler = handlerFunc();
    // handler now contains the instance you're interested in
}
```

If you can ensure that your calls to `Subscribe` are always of the form you gave, then this should work, but it's extremely brittle.

It's also worth storing `handlerFunc` rather than `handler`, because a call to `Subscribe<EventArgs>(() => handler.EventHandler)` creates a closure which captures the `handler` variable, *not* its value. As such if you were to set `handler` to `null`, or to a different value after the call to `Subscribe`, it'll be the new value's `EventHandler` that will get called, not the value at the time of the `Subscribe` call.