# Is there a short and simple way for checking variable/property values?

Tags: c#, exception

I wonder whether there is a short and simple way for checking whether variable/property values match some condition?

Currently one of the most popular line in my code is similar to this one:

```
if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(someFileName)) 
{
    throw new NullReferenceException("'someFileName' must not be null.");
}
```

then the exception gets logged in the catch part and the execution continues and so on.

I don't like writing this line all over the place and just changing the variable name. It would be great if one could write something like this:

```
Assert.IsNotNullOrWhiteSpace(someFileName);
```

and it threw an exception saying that "{my variable} must not be null" with maybe some additional information like the parent class etc. that would help you to debug the code if you only have the logs available.

The problem with writing such a utility class that I encountered was that the thrown exception had of course the wrong stack trace like it happened in the utility method and not inside the method that called the assertion function.

This kind of value checking is required to especially work at runtime because I most of the time check user input like settings, paths, inputs etc.

EDIT:

I think I should have given an example of what I try to achieve:

```
public class FileExtractor {
    public Form MainForm { get; set; }
    public void ExtractFile(string fileName) {
        Assert.IsNotNullOrWhiteSpace(fileName);
        Assert.IsNotNull(MainForm);
        // ...
    }
}
```

and the let's call it Assert library should do this:

```
public static Assert {
    public static void IsNotNullOrWhiteSpace(this string value) {
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(value)) {
            // throw an exception like it occured in the ExtractFile
            // the message should contain a hint like: "fileName must not be null"
        }
    }

public static void IsNotNull(this object value) {
    if (value == null) {
        // throw an excaption like it occured in the ExtractFile, 
        // the messagge should contain a hint like: "FileExtractor.MainForm must not be null."
    }
}
```

EDIT-2

@[CodeCaster](https://stackoverflow.com/users/266143/codecaster) - unfortunately I cannot not use C# 6 yet.

After some research and inspirated by two other questions here on stackoverflow

[How to get Property Value from MemberExpression without .Compile()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19718560/how-to-get-property-value-from-memberexpression-without-compile)

and

[get name of a variable or parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9801624/get-name-of-a-variable-or-parameter)

I came up with this so far:

```
namespace ExceptionTest
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            object test = null;
            Assert.IsNotNull(() => test);
        }
    }

    static class Assert
    {
        public static void IsNotNull<T>(Expression<Func<T>> expression)
        {
            MemberExpression memberExpr = expression.Body as MemberExpression;
            var constExpr = memberExpr.Expression as ConstantExpression;
            var value = (memberExpr.Member as FieldInfo).GetValue(constExpr.Value);
            if (value == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException(memberExpr.Member.Name);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It almost does what I need. The last thing is to modify the stack trace so that it points to the `Main` method and not to the `IsNotNull`

Comment: *"the thrown exception had of course the wrong stack trace like it happened in the utility method"* Does this really matter? The stack trace should still include the path where it's been called.

Comment: Any chance of using C# 6? Search for `nameof()`.

Comment: You should almost never throw `NullReferenceException` yourself. You should throw `ArgumentNullException` if necessary - but *not* if the value is actually a reference to an empty string.

Comment: At least you need to pass variable name as well: `Assert.IsNotNullOrWhiteSpace(someFileName, "someFileName");`

Comment: This is what I actually want to avoid passing the variable as a string because it is error prone. You refactor something and the wrong variable name remains there unchanged.

Comment: I see the StackTrace property of the Exception class is virtual. I will try to modify it. Perhaps it is even possible to delete some frames so that the logging inside the assert method (it would be great to have it there) logs the original caller as the excption source.

Comment: I'm not sure whether it is visible to all but I edited my original post EDIT-2 and added a partial solution.

Answer (score 0):

You could use **Debug Methods** (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Diagnostics.Debug_methods%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), which however only work when compiling in debug mode.

Maybe `Debug.WriteLineIf(Boolean, String)` does what you need?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y94y4370%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

How about applying attributes to the properties
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd901590(VS.95).aspx

Answer (score 0):

I think that you should try with [Fody library](https://github.com/Fody/Fody) library. For null-guards there is a package that you can find [here](https://github.com/Fody/NullGuard). All libs are available via Nuget.

Fody is some kind AOP library that uses "weaving" technique to manipulate IL of an assembly and inject additional code.

So `NullReferenceExcpetion` (or maybe `NullArgumentException`) will be thrown exactly from your method.

Example from GitHub:

**Your code**

```
public void SomeMethod(string arg)
{
    // throws ArgumentNullException if arg is null.
}

public void AnotherMethod([AllowNull] string arg)
{
    // arg may be null here
}
```

**What gets complied**

```
public void SomeMethod(string arg)
{
    if (arg == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("arg");
    }
}
public void AnotherMethod(string arg)
{
}
```